# How to know which Metal texture format to use? short or half?

Tags: graphics, textures, metal, metalkit

Apple's Metal examples alternate between using `texture2D<float>` and `texture2D<half>`, and I believe that the default pixel format of a `MTKView` is `bgra8unorm`. What determines if I should use `float` or `half`? Do I need to specify something on the CPU, or will textures using 128-bits-in-all `float4s` be converted into `halfs` automatically? How about the other way around if I pass-in a texture with a bgra8format? I am asking because I am trying to load textures using MTKTextureLoader as well as from plain byte data, and I'm not sure what format to use for the plain byte data so things are consistent. May I have clarification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on your use case.

*Loading*: You can probably safely load your data into a texture with the same format as that data. When your render destination has a different format, Metal will perform the conversion for you.

*Intermediates*: The format of intermediate textures should really depend on the "resolution" (as in "number of bits") you need, which depends on the input data and the color space. If you only handle sRGB data, 8-bit textures are probably enough (unless you do some complicated processing that requires a higher precision). If you want to support a wide gamut (e.g. in Display P3 color space), you need more precision (`half` should be fine) and also want to be able to store values outside of the [0...255] range. On iOS I'd recommend using `half` for memory efficiency (and since most devices don't support full float anyway), on macOS `float` is the default, I think.

*View*: The pixel format of the view should really depend on the display. Most of the screens support the Display P3 color space now. For that, you should use the `bgra10_xr` format, since it's optimized for that case. Otherwise `bgra8unorm` is fine.

In general, you should be using a texture format with the smallest memory footprint that fits your use case.

Comment: That helps. I didn't realize that Metal would perform the conversions. For clarification, my target is a recent iPad model (so mobile). Just a few of follow-up questions based on some points in your answer: 
1: should the return type from the fragment shaders ALSO be half if I want optimal performance?
2: if I am loading textures from pngs, should I assume that they are SRGB? (The MTKTextureLoader has a field to specify this.) 
3: if I am using multisampling on my view, does this mean that all textures need to have multisampling and a specific kind of sampler in the shader?

Comment: 1. I think it's best to use `half` everywhere except when you really need `float` precision. 2. It depends if your image has a linear or an sRGB gamma curve. I think the loader chooses the correct option if you don't pass that option. 3. I don't think so, but I'm no expert on MSAA. From what I understand, you just render into the `multisampleColorTexture` of the view and it will resolve automatically.

Comment: Thanks. It’s incredibly challenging sometimes to find answers about Metal deapite it already being around for a while.